# HTTP Request inside an AsyncTask

Tags: android, request, android-asynctask

I have an HTTP Request that parses an XML file.
I'm trying to connect to internet from an asyntask but I have not been able

I do this and works by putting the code inside a thread, but not inside an AsycTask
The problem I have is that the HTTP Request is called within a String with this line of code:

```
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
```

Running this

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
            Thread t= new Thread(){
                public void run() {
                    xml = null;              
                    try {
                        Log.i("Log1","Parse");
                        // defaultHttpClient
                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml");

                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                }
            };
            t.start();
            return xml;
        }

        final Runnable mUpdateResults =new Runnable (){
            public void run(){//2

            }
        };
```

As I mentioned, the HTTP Request is within a thread, but I always find errors when I try to put it inside a AsycTask ... I do not know how do it.

I have been referred to the documentation of AsycTask and have read many times, I have searched tutorials, but I could not build it correctly.

After two days, i begin to be a little desperate

I put the complete code for my work, if anyone can tell me how to replace a AsyncTask thread, I'll be very grateful.

Thank you very much and regards

*full activity:*

```
public class PruebasActivity extends Activity {


    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
    // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
        static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
        static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
        static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;

        ListView list;
        LazyAdapter adapter;
        String xml;

        final Handler mHandler=new Handler();


        // constructor
        public void XMLParser() {

        }

        /**
         * Cogiendo el XML de la URL mediante HTTP request
         * @param url string
         * */
        public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
            Thread t= new Thread(){
                public void run() {
                    xml = null;              
                    try {
                        Log.i("Log1","Parse");
                        // defaultHttpClient
                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml");

                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                }
            };
            t.start();
            return xml;
        }

        final Runnable mUpdateResults =new Runnable (){
            public void run(){//2

            }
        };

        /*
         * @param XML string
         * */
        public Document getDomElement(String xml){
            Document doc = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
        }

        /*
         * @param elem element
         */
        public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
            Node child;
            if( elem != null){
                if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                    for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                        if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                            return child.getNodeValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        /*
         * @param Element node
         * @param key string
         * */
        public String getValue(Element item, String str) {      
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // Cogiendo XML de la URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // Cogiendo DOM de los elementos

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));          

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        // Pasando datos parseados del adaptador al arrayList
        adapter=new MinAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you posted the code that you use when you are attempting it in an AsyncTask along with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP request can be run in the doInBackground function of Asynctask and your runnable is the onPostExecute function.
The result is this :

```
public class XmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    public String doInBackground(String... urls){
        String url = urls[0];

        // Place your getXmlFromUrl content here

        return xml;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String xml){
        // Your XML parsing staement here
    }
}
```

In this code, Thread and runnable are unnecessary.

And in your activity just tap:

```
new XmlTask().execute("http://yoururl");
```

Comment: hi
I get an error when I attach the adapter to the listview in OnPostExecute

songsList = new ArrayList <HashMap <String, String>> ();
...
adapter = new MinAdapter (this, songsList);
list.setAdapter (adapter);

MinAdapter method, which belongs to MinAdapter activity:

   public MinAdapter (Activity a, ArrayList <HashMap <String, String>> d) {
         activity = a;
         data = d;
         inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         imageLoader = new ImageLoader (activity.getApplicationContext ());
     }

Where is the error?

thanks

Comment: can you post your stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you. Try it:

```
public class PruebasActivity extends Activity {

static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    String xml;

    // constructor
    public void XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Cogiendo el XML de la URL mediante HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
            xml = null;              
            try {
                Log.i("Log1","Parse");
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml");

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return xml;
    }


    /*
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    /*
     * @param elem element
     */
    public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
        Node child;
        if( elem != null){
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                    if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    /*
     * @param Element node
     * @param key string
     * */
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> ast = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        ProgressDialog p;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             p = new ProgressDialog(EditTextDemoActivity.this);
            //write code to start the progress dialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // Cogiendo XML de la URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // Cogiendo DOM de los elementos

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));          

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p.dismiss();
            adapter=new MinAdapter(this, songsList);        
            lst.setAdapter(adapter); 
        }
    };

    ast.execute();
}
}
```

I have implemented the code using `AsyncTask`. You don't need any other `Thread` to implement background activity when you are using `AsyncTask`. I have left a small part of coding (to create and display a progress dialog) as an exercise for you.

Hope this helps.